# Two "Submit" buttons on AngularJS Bootstrap Form triggered by Enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a search modal that has two buttons I want to trigger on pressing enter. There is the initial "Search" button, and then a final "Submit" button.

The user is in an Angular Modal, puts a name into a search field (During this time, the Submit button is disabled) and then would press "Enter" to initiate the search. The search populates a table, after which the user clicks on a name to select and then the Submit button is enabled, and now I want a keypress of "Enter" to submit the selection.

I can get the first "Enter" to run the search functionality, but can't get it to move to the second button. Here is the code for my first button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default "ng-click="getNames(params)" value="Search">Search</button>
<button class="btn btn-default " type="button" ng-click="Clear(params)">Clear</button>
```

And then once the list of names populates, the user selects one and then should be able to press "Enter" again to trigger the Submit button.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="OK()" ng-disabled="disableOK()"/>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="Cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Using `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default "ng-click="OK()" g-disabled="disableOK()"></button>` Doesn't work here either.

I've looked everywhere since this seems like it would be a common problem, but I haven't seen a fix for this, mostly it's people with multiple buttons wanting to do different things on submit, not triggering with the "Enter" key.

Can I assign it to be the default when it becomes enabled?

Comment: Why do you need to call both functions from the enter key? Why don't you just call the other function from the one triggered on enter? 

Like this:

function1() {
//do stuff

function2();
};

Comment: @StevenMays I want to call them both using the Enter key because my users want keyboard-accessible input. Calling the Submit button off of the Search function won't work because the user hasn't made the selection they need before Submitting.

Comment: just add event listener for keypress and trigger whatever. Default browser behavior (enter -> submit button) is not that flexible.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov how would I do this?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/lsconyer/bktpzgre/1/